# Construct truth table based on circuit given.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

I need help with this circuit Boolean algebra question. The question and the image for figure 1 is below.

> Write the input/output truth table for the circuit in figure 1. $A$ and $B$ are inputs and $X$ is output.

[image: Figure 1, Circuit 1]

| $A$ | $B$ | $A∨B$ | $¬B$ | $(A∨B)∧¬B$ | $X (~(A∨B)∧¬B)$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I am asked to build a truth table based on the figure (figure shown) that has 1 OR gate, 2 NOT gates, and 1 AND gate. Based on the figure and information given, I have set up my truth table. My question: Is the first row of my truth table setup correctly? $A, B,    A∨B , ¬B,  (A∨B)∧¬B,  X (~(A∨B)∧¬B)$. I am unsure if I did it correctly since some of my other classmates have received an $X$ output of $1,1,1,1$

Comment: The third row should give 0 which you got. Your classmates made an error.

Comment: Just simplify the boolean expression $\overline{(A+B) \cdot \overline{B}} = \overline{A}+B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your truth table is correct. However, I am assuming that $$X((A \lor B)\land \not B $$
You are taking its negotation right? As there is a "NOT" before the X.

However, checking the A and B inputs with the end result X, it yields 1 1 0 1, which is correct.

Comment: Yes, for X I am taking its negation. I forgot to add it in. Thank you!